# How to convert typescript types of strings to array of strings?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I've this type:

```
type myCustomType = "aaa" | "bbb" | "ccc";
```

I need to convert it to an array like this:

```
["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

How can I do this in typescript?

Comment: Not possible, types are not in emitted code. But you could do it the other way around - define the array, then create a type from it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `const arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] as const;
type arrTypes = typeof arr[number];`

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Ah...I missed out the `as const` part. I think that would be a good answer, I suggest posting it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay thanks for the quick answer. I will go with that solution then - that could also solve my scenario :)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Types do not exist in emitted code - you can't go from a *type* to an *array*.

But you could go the other way around, in some situations. If the array is not dynamic (or its values can be completely determined by the type-checker at the time it's initialized), you can declare the array `as const` (so that the array's type is `["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]` rather than `string[]`), and then create a type from it by mapping its values from `arr[number]`:

```
const arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] as const;
type myCustomType = typeof arr[number];
```

Here's an example [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gIjjzAaGTAIxP0OAswF14IZRIoBuAKCgE8AHAUxgFt2AYQCu0EHwAqXXmg48QAM3hJ0YYXyLcEVViwA23WAA8AXPyGio4qT1SEccTKwOx2ZgSLGTpdzAC8ApxgAemCYAFEkEAQgA).

Comment: what does [number] here mean?

Comment: It evaluates to the union of `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, etc; `arr[someNumber]` where `someNumber` is a number. It's TypeScript syntax only, not JS.

Comment: What means the `as const` part?

Comment: @adrisons It keeps TypeScript from automatically widening the type to `string[]`, and instead keeps it as a static tuple of `["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]`

Comment: **Fun Fact:** You can actually name both the `const` and the `type` **with the same name**. When you import it as a type, TypeScript ensures you cannot use it as a regular array. When you import it as a regular array, TypeScript correctly identifies where it is used as a type and where it is used as a regular array.

Answer (score 9):

For example:

```
  const themeMode = ['light', 'dark'] as const;
  type MainTheme = typeof themeMode[number];
  const values = [...themeMode];

  // iterate on themeMode as const assertion
  values.map((theme) => console.log(theme));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing this using an intermediary, "throwaway" object, which the compiler will ensure must contain *exactly* all the possible type values (no more or less):

```
type myCustomType = "aaa" | "bbb" | "ccc";
const myCustomTypeObject: {
  [key in myCustomType]: undefined;
} = { aaa: undefined, bbb: undefined, ccc: undefined };
const myCustomTypeArray = Object.keys(myCustomTypeObject);
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a slightly longer version, which tidies up by setting the intermediary object to `undefined` afterwards since it is unlikely to be needed again.

```
type myCustomType = "aaa" | "bbb" | "ccc";
let tempMyCustomTypeObject:
  | {
      [key in myCustomType]: undefined;
    }
  | undefined = { aaa: undefined, bbb: undefined, ccc: undefined };
const myCustomTypeArray = Object.keys(tempMyCustomTypeObject);
tempMyCustomTypeObject = undefined;
```

Comment: Why would we do this? The other answers are much cleaner and don't repeat the strings.

Comment: @ADTC The question is asking how to convert a type to an array. As of writing, the accepted answer is saying it can't be done and instead answers the other way round (array=>type). And the other answer is doing similar. In my case, this wasn't useful as I needed to convert a type defined in an external library into an array to be used in a JSON schema. With this solution, the Typescript compilation will fail unless the array is 100% aligned with the type. The intermediary code may not appear "clean" but it's the best I could come up with to address the original question.