# How get convert typescript defined types of strings to array of strings

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm tryining get all defined types from variable in construct.

```
export interface TestType {
  resultType?: 'NUMBER' | 'STRING' | 'DATE' | 'ENUM' | 'AMOUNT' ;
}
```

And I expect the result of something like this.

```
const types: string[] = ['NUMBER', 'STRING', 'DATE', 'ENUM', 'AMOUNT'];
```

There may be a function or ability to achieve this from constructor. When the contrustor cannot be changed?

I try to automate it so that it basically extracts all types and I was able to get them to select.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59857223/how-to-convert-typescript-types-of-strings-to-array-of-strings) is just one example that this is not possible.

Or ideas for similar solutions?

Actual I am currently using Typescript in v4.0.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is something similar to iterate over possible values of a variable. Types need to be refered to in a static final way in typescript.

```
export class TestClass{
    types = ['NUMBER', 'STRING', 'DATE', 'ENUM', 'AMOUNT'] as const;
    resultType: TestClass["types"][number];
}
```

In the above example the accepted values of *resultType* are members of the *types* Array. So type validation will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As these types do not exist at runtime, you cannot generate the strings directly.
You could create some helper that will ensure that you use only the right keys.

```
type Types = 'foo'|'bar'|'baz';

type TypeHolder<T extends string> = { [Key in T]: number; }

function getKeys<T extends string>(types: TypeHolder<T>) {
    return Object.keys(types);
}

console.log(getKeys<Types>({ foo: 1, bar: 1, baz: 1 }));  // ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Hmm, not really nice. It's probably much easier to do it the other way around:

```
const types = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const;
type Types = typeof types[number];   // 'foo'|'bar'|'baz'
```